# What's happening in my object renaming script?

Tags: python, rename, maya

please bear with me, with my questions especially... 
I apologize in advance should my thread title misleads you in some ways but this is the best I can come up with

I am doing a basic renaming application as shown in the code below. 
Basically I took this from an example that I have came across, slap it into my code and viola, it works. Sadly there are a few parts in which I do not understand and as I tried searching online for answers, I came up with nothing and it sure is frustrating.

```
import pymel.core as pm
objects = pm.ls(selection=True)
# Result: [nt.Transform(u'my_pCube1')] # 
pfx = 'test'

for item in objects:
    item.rename(pfx + "_" + item.name().split('|')[-1])
    print 'Prefix added: %s_' %pfx
```

1. Is `[nt.Transform(u'my_pCube1')]` considered a long name or short name in this instance?
2. where does `.name()` came from? Is it a part of the rename hidden functions or something which I am not seeing from the documentation?

Then, as I am using `cmds` almost throughout my coding, I thought I might as well standardized it and changed `pm` to `cmds`... However instead of running as I thought it would, it gives me the error as shown below.

```
objects = cmds.ls(selection=True)
# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'rename' #
```

1. Why is it so?
2. Additionally, as I tried to print out the output of `objects`, it prints out objects instead of the selection.. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe look into Maya's API documentation. Also, it is not clear from your post that you're working with that API.

Answer (score 2):

your sample is using PyMel, so the objects in your lists are PyNodes as @vaibhaw points out. They are useful in this situation because they retain a connection to the original scene objects.

The long name of a maya object is the name in the form |path|to|object  where the names off all the objects above it in the hierarchy are the included.  To get this from a pynode use the fullPath() function on your nodes

The short name is **usually** the name displayed in the outliner or channel box for an object. When you have more than one object with the same short name, maya will give you enough of the long name to differentiate  the objects. For a hierarchy like:

```
group1
  box
group2 
  box
```

the shortNames will be `|group1|box` and `|group2|box`. Get this from a pynode with shortName(); it's what you would get using plain old maya or mel.

To get the name you see in the channel box from a pynode, use nodeName().  That gives you only the object's 'personal' name.

If you use pynodes, you should be able to just call rename() on each object. However you'll need to keep the objects around to check their new names -- the new names may not be exactly what you want, since Maya won't allow sibling objects to have the same name; it will rename siblings with a trailing number to keep them unique.

In the second bit of code you're using maya.cmds.  It does not operate on objects with their own functions, it treats all objects as strings.  So

```
pynode = pm.PyNode("pCube1")
pynode.rename("fred")
print pynode
# Result: [nt.Transform(u'fred')] #
```

in pymel, but in maya.cmds, the obects are just strings:

```
cube = "pCube1"
renamed_cube = cmds.rename(cube, "barney")
print renamed_cube:
#  Result: barney #
```

Comment: I get what you meant by the long and short names, however, I am still confused about the code I have posted.. I believed for mine, it is reading and printing out short names but still, where does the `split` comes from in the first place? It does not even have `|`

Comment: It is true that there is no `|` in object name. So there is no need to use split. Although it still works because if `separator` (`|` here) is not present in string, `split()` returns a list containing only 1 element which is the original string(name of object). `list[-1]` is the last element in `list`. Since only 1 element is present in list so `list[-1]` gives you object name. Hence in this case `item.name().split('|')[-1]` is eventually `item.name()`

Comment: @vaibhaw Thank you for the explanation. I did a quick experimentation and the theory works. However, When I am testing it out with `[0]` instead of `[-1]`, the code works and give the same output as well. Does this means for the `0` (refers to the first element, I presume) equals to the same as `-1` (last element)?

Comment: That's true. `some_list[0]` is the first element of list `some_list`. When there is only one element in list, it can be accessed both as `[0]` and `[-1]` because it is both the first and last element. In a list having `n` elements you can access it in 2 ways: 
1. `for item in objects: ...` OR 2. Using index(i.e. position) of item in list. `list[x-1]` will give you xth element of list from `list[0]` (first element) to `list[n-1]`(last element). You can also access the elements of list backwards from `list[-1]`(last element) to `list[-n]`(first element).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that pm is `pymel.core` module. See the documentation of this module [here](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/ja_jp/PyMel/generated/functions/pymel.core.general/pymel.core.general.ls.html#pymel-core-general-ls). `ls` method in pymel.core module returns a list of PyNode objects.

Read about PyNodes [here](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/ja_jp/PyMel/pynodes.html?#pynodes). Specially read the sections `PyNodes Are Not Strings` and `Mutability and You` which mentions that
    `rename` method can be used for PyNode objects.

Look into documentation of [ls](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/ls.html) and [rename](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/rename.html) methods in cmds. 
`ls` returns an array of string variables(names of objects), not the objects themselves. And strings have no method called `rename`, hence you are getting the `AttributeError`.

To rename using cmds, this may work:

```
objects = cmds.ls(selection=True)
pfx = 'test'

for item in objects:
    cmds.rename(item, pfx + "_" + item)
    # cmds.rename(old_filename, new_filename)
    print 'Prefix added: %s_' %pfx
```

Code not tested as I do not have Maya installed.

`.name()` is an attribute of `PyNode` object.